# Shifting a vector of strings down one position constantly C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm working on a simple text editor for a class right now in C++. It uses a std::vector of strings to let users insert text. A row is basically a new line where text is inserted, and a column is where the cursor currently is.

When the user inserts a new line, it should shift any text underneath it down by one as well. As of right now, I can shift text on a current line down by one line, but all the text underneath stays until my cursor hits that single line. Here is the current insertNewLine() code I'm executing.

```
void Editor::insertNewLine()
{
    std::string currLine = lines[row];
    size_t tempSize = currLine.size();
    int lengthOffset = getSubstringOffset(tempSize, column);
    std::string cutTemp = currLine.substr(column, lengthOffset); // our string for the new line
    lines[row].erase(column); // erase the line we are shifting down
    // after incrementing, row and amount of lines, initialize the new row
    numberOfLines++;
    lines.push_back("");
    row++;
    column = 1;
    lines[row] += cutTemp; // insert substring into new line
}
```

In my code, my substring methods work just fine, and if I don't have any text beneath a row I want to insert in, the method itself works. But, if I decide to insert a new line with text, above a row this happens (the | is representing the cursor):

```
Before

Line 1. Hello
Line 2. |w
Line 3. orld

After inserting a new line at line 2.

Line 1. Hello
Line 2. 
Line 3. |orldw
Line 4.
```

Here is what **should** technically happen:

```
Before

Line 1. Hello
Line 2. |w
Line 3. orld

After inserting a new line at line 2

Line 1. Hello
Line 2. 
Line 3. |w
Line 4. orld
```

Is there some (easy/fast) way to shift every string element in the vector past a certain row down by one? And will it work for an empty line as well?

Comment: Assuming that each line is a separate entry in the vector, what's wrong with just using [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)? That function will handle the "shifting" automatically.

Comment: `lines.insert(lines.begin() + row, "");`

Comment: @user657267 That fixed it, didn't realize push_back wasn't handling all of that. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Why would `push_back` handle shifting other elements? You're pushing to the end of the vector, there are no elements after the end!

Comment: @user657267 You are right, I didn't think about that :| By the way, anytime I move up to a row that is empty by doing row--; or moving down from a row that is empty by doing row++; I get this error: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string. Any idea why?

Comment: @Alex You're probably trying to insert into an invalid position, it's hard to say just from what you described.

Comment: @user657267 I'm implementing code to move the cursor down. If the length of the string is bigger than the one underneath, I move to the end of that string. If the string I am currently on is less than the one underneath, I move down to the column based on the previous strings size. here is the code for it: http://pastebin.com/zfudAEE1

Comment: @Alex there's nothing in the code you posted that can cause an `out_of_range` exception. Read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and create a new question with your current issue.